# How does one add a new country in Magento? (Curacao)

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, magento-1.7

I've tried to add a country in Magento 1.7.0.2. I tried following this 'solution':
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/226473/

> 1. Open lib/zend/locale/data/en.xml
> 2. Locate territories tag in this file
> 3. copy one of territory tags for the syntax and paste it within the territories tag
> 4. hard part here is to add country code in this file as might not be able to find a unique one, so it’s upto you.
> 5. Save this file
> 6. Open table name directory_country
> 7. It has predefined syntax follow then same and create a new row and enter the same country code as entered in the en.xml file in 3
>    columns.
> 8. Refresh the site’s cache.
> 9. Admin > Configuration > General this new country should be selected in list of allowed countries.

So I added this line in `lib/zend/locale/data/en.xml`:

```
<territory type="CW">Curacao</territory>
```

And the following in MySQL:
In directory_country

> country_id    iso2_code   iso3_code
>
> CW            CW          CUW

Next, I cleared the cache.. and Curacao was nowhere to be found. Does somebody know what's going wrong. Is it possible to add a country?

Thanks a lot

---

**Edit:**
I fixed my own problem, here's the solution:
Do everything as I said above, but make sure you add the territory tag to en.xml but also to whatever xml your storeview uses. In my case I had a Dutch storeview and it uses the dutch xml files, so I put the same exact territory tag in the nl.xml files.
Next, clear your cache and it appears in the dropdown menus!

Comment: feel free to post an answer to your own question